# Nested RecyclerView. How to prevent parent RecyclerView from getting scrolled while child RecyclerView is scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I am trying to implement a horizontal `recyclerview` and each item of the `recyclerview` will be a vertical `recyclerview` with a grid layout. The problem that i am facing is that when I try to scroll the child `recyclerview` vertically sometimes the parent `recyclerview` takes the scroll and starts scrolling horizontally. The approaches I tried to fix this are,

1. `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` on the parent `recyclerview`
2. In the `onTouch()` of the child `recyclerview` I disable touch events on the parent `recyclerview` by called `requestdisallowinterceptTouchevent(false)`

None of the above solutions provide a perfect fix for the problem. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 33):

The problem seemed interesting to me. So I tried to implement and this is what I achieved (you can also see the [video here](http://sendvid.com/6mp8bstd)) which is pretty smooth.

[image]

So you can try something like this:

Define `CustomLinearLayoutManager` extending `LinearLayoutManager` like this:

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and set this `CustomLinearLayoutManager` to your parent `RecyclerView`.

```
RecyclerView parentRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.parent_rv);
CustomLinearLayoutManager customLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
parentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(customLayoutManager);
parentRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ParentAdapter(this)); // some adapter
```

Now for child `RecyclerView`, define custom `CustomGridLayoutManager` extending `GridLayoutManager`:

```
public class CustomGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

    public CustomGridLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public CustomGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
    }

    public CustomGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and set it as `layoutManger` to the child `RecyclerView`:

```
childRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_rv);
childRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new CustomGridLayoutManager(context, 3));
childRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ChildAdapter()); // some adapter
```

So basically parent `RecyclerView` is only listening to horizontal scrolls and child `RecyclerView` is only listening to vertical scrolls.

Along with that, if you also want to handle diagonal swipe (which is little skewed to either vertical or horizontal), you can include a gesture listener in the **parent** `RecylerView`.

```
public class ParentRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public ParentRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getContext(), new XScrollDetector());
       // do the same in other constructors
    }

   // and override onInterceptTouchEvent

   @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

Where `XScrollDetector` is

```
class XScrollDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return Math.abs(distanceY) < Math.abs(distanceX);
        }
}
```

Thus `ParentRecyclerView` asks child view (in our case, VerticalRecyclerView) to handle the scroll event. If the child view handles then parent does nothing else parent eventually handles the scroll.

Comment: Extending linear layout was a great advice. I almost changed my whole implementation to NestedScrollList. Looks like it saved me that effort.

Comment: Amazing answer, in my case I didn't need to use the entire solution, only the SimpleOnGestureListener part and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, when using `LinearLayoutManager` it's enough to restrict diagonal scrolling.

Comment: No need of extending LinearLayoutManager because of explicitly disable horizontal / vertical scroll as you can see the implementation of [canScrollHorizontally](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#canscrollhorizontally) / [canScrollVertically](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#canscrollvertically) methods it is already using orientation you provide in constructor.

Answer (score 8):

> setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) on the parent recyclerview

What you could try is `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` on the *child* RecyclerView, if any. RecyclerView 's nestedscroll-ness is that of a child (that's why it implements `NestedScrollingChild`).

> In the onTouch() of the child recyclerview I disable touch events on
>   the parent recyclerview by called
>   requestdisallowinterceptTouchevent(false)

This should work, but what you should do is `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`, not `false`. If you subclass RecyclerView, you can override `onTouchEvent`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // ensure we release the disallow request when the finger is lifted
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    } else {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    // Call the super class to ensure touch handling
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Or, with a touch listener from outside,

```
child.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == child.getId()) {
            if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // ensure we release the disallow request when the finger is lifted
                child.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            } else {
                child.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        }
        // Call the super class to ensure touch handling
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this issue in a similar project by taking the opposite approach to you (and everyone else here).

Rather than allow the child to tell the parent when to stop looking at events, I let the parent decide when to ignore (based on direction). This approach requires a custom view though which can be a little more work. Below is what I created which would be used as the Outer/Parent view.

```
public class DirectionalRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private static float LOCK_DIRECTION_THRESHOLD; //The slop
    private float startX;
    private float startY;
    private LockDirection mLockDirection = null;

    public DirectionalRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        findThreshold(context);
    }

    public DirectionalRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        findThreshold(context)
    }

    public DirectionalRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        findThreshold(context);
    }

    private void findThreshold(Context context) {
        //last number is number of dp to move before deciding that's a direction not a tap, you might want to tweak it
        LOCK_DIRECTION_THRESHOLD = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 12;
    }

    //events start at the top of the tree and then pass down to
    //each child view until they reach where they were initiated
    //unless the parent (this) method returns true for this visitor
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mLockDirection == null) {
                    float currentX = event.getX();
                    float currentY = event.getY();
                    float diffX = Math.abs(currentX - startX);
                    float diffY = Math.abs(currentY - startY);
                    if (diffX > LOCK_DIRECTION_THRESHOLD) {
                        mLockDirection = LockDirection.HORIZONTAL;
                    } else if (diffY > LOCK_DIRECTION_THRESHOLD) {
                        mLockDirection = LockDirection.VERTICAL;
                    }
                } else {
                    //we have locked a direction, check whether we intercept
                    //the future touches in this event chain
                    //(returning true steals children's events, otherwise we'll
                    // just let the event trickle down to the child as usual)
                    return mLockDirection == LockDirection.HORIZONTAL;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mLockDirection = null;
                break;
        }
        //dispatch cancel, clicks etc. normally
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private enum LockDirection {
        HORIZONTAL,
        VERTICAL
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked for me for a different scenario - horizontal RV containing coordinator containing collapsing toolbar and nested scroll view. The only thing that had to change is to set `mLockDirection = null;` in `dispatchTouchEvent()` because in `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()` are not called in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for this valueable approach. The approach to handle this kind of stuff in parent is so much easier. I succeeded in making a vertical inside a horizontal viewpager with your modified logic.

Answer (score 5):

Now you can try `android:nestedScrollingEnabled` because Google fixed a crash with usages of `nestedScrollingEnabled` [(Issue 197932)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197932)

Answer (score 5):

Set the listener to nested RecyclerView

```
 View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                            ) {
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    } else {
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

            mRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Comment: How does this works? Can you please explain a little?

Comment: It disallow the intercept touch event of parent RecyclerView when nested RecyclerView is being scrolled.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. For my use-case it has worked:

```
nestedRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try the below code, hope it will work.

```
nestedRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                   switch (action) {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     // Disallow parent to intercept touch events.
                     v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                     break;

                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow parent to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
        }

                  // Handle inner(child) touch events.
                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

I used card view for cells and deactivated parent recycler view scrolling in child adapter with child cell itemView `setOnClickListener`.

```
holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener { view, _ ->
    view.parent.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
    false
}
```

we are calling `view.parent.parent` because of the fact that `itemView` is a cell layout and it's parent is our child `recyclerView` and also, we need to reach child recyclerView's parent to prevent parent `recyclerView` scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to scroll inner RecyclerView.

```
innerRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent event) {
            // Handle on touch events here
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow Parent RecyclerView to intercept touch events.
                    recycler.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow Parent RecyclerView to intercept touch events.
                    recycler.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you can try the following inside the Adapter of outer RecyclerView:

```
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        RVAdapter2 recyclerViewAdapter2 = new RVAdapter2();
        RecyclerView innerRV = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv2);
        // Setup layout manager for items
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(parent.getContext());
        // Control orientation of the items
        layoutManager2.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        innerRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);
        innerRV.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter2);

        innerRV.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                recyclerView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        });

        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }
```

For API23, you can also try `innerRV.setOnScrollChangeListener` because `setOnScrollListener` is deprecated.

### UPDATE:

Another option is using `addOnScrollListener` instead of `setOnScrollListener`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to turn off scroll on `recyclerview`:

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should do this way:**

```
innerRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent event) {
            // Handle on touch events here
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    recycler.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    recycler.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    recycler.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    break;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: if you return false in onInterceptTouchEvent, onTouchEvent will never be called

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists in Android's implementation of the onInterceptTouchEvent() method for RecyclerView.
This blog calls out the problem and fixes it as well - http://nerds.headout.com/fix-horizontal-scrolling-in-your-android-app/.
The only difference is that there the parent scrolls vertically and child horizontally. But the solution takes care that it should work for your situation as well.

Comment: Just in case anyone wondered, the linked article now gives a 404... but don't panic, it has been mirrored somewhere in China : https://www.tuicool.com/articles/ENbiqi

Answer (score -1):

extend a custom layout manager  like this

```
 public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
 private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

 public CustomGridLayoutManager(Context context) {
 super(context);
        }
  @Override
 public boolean canScrollVertically() {
 return false;
 }
}
```

Set the layout manager to this "Custom layout Manager"